# Find the matrix representing T and Find the Image of T (as a span of vectors)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T(a,b) = (a+b,2a-b,3a)$.

a)Find the matrix representing $T$. 
b)Find the image of $T$ (as a span of vectors).

So I found that $T$ is a linear transformation. Now would the matrix just be 
$A$= $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\2 & -1\\ 3 &0\end{bmatrix}$? 
I feel like this would be too easy.

Also how would I go about finding the image of $T$?

Comment: The matrix you found is correct.

The image of $T$ is the span of the columns of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear map $T:F^2 \to F^3$ is determined by what it does to the basis elements. Using the standard basis $\mathbf{B}=((1,0),(0,1))$, we obtain:

$$\begin{align} T(1,0)=(1,2,3) &=1\cdot (1,0,0)+2 \cdot (0,1,0)+3 \cdot (0,0,1) \\&= 1 \cdot \mathbf{e_1} + 2 \cdot \mathbf{e_2}+3 \cdot \mathbf{e_3} \\&= \left(1,2,3 \right)^{t}(\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\mathbf{e_3}) \\&= A_1 \mathbf{B^\prime}, \end{align}$$ and $$\begin{align} T(0,1)=(1,-1,0) &= 1 \cdot (1,0,0)+-1 \cdot (0,1,0) + 0 \cdot (0,0,1) \\&= 1 \cdot \mathbf{e_1} -1 \cdot \mathbf{e_2}+0 \cdot \mathbf{e_3} \\&= A_2 \mathbf{B^\prime}. \end{align}$$ where $\mathbf{B^\prime}=(\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\mathbf{e_3})$ is the standard basis of $F^3$. To obtain the desired matrix, combine the coordinate vectors $A_1$ and $A_2$: $$A= ( A_1 \hspace{2mm} A_2)= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 \\ 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ 
which is the matrix that you got.

Let $X \in F^2$. Then the image of $T$ (or column space of $A$) is: $$\begin{align} AX=  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 \\ 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} &= A_1x_1 + A_2x_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}  \\&=  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} x_1 +  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}x_2, \quad x_1,x_2 \in F \\&= \text{span} \left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  \right) \\&= \text{span}(A_1,A_2) \subset F^3. \end{align}$$

Edit: In this case, you do not need to row reduce $A$, because $A_1$ and $A_2$ are already linearly independent. The image of $T$ is just the column space of $A$, and the column space is the $\text{span}$ of the columns. If the column space contains two linearly independent vectors, then it is just the $\text{span}$ of those two vectors.

Comment: I don't need to row reduce an augmented matrix to find the span? I thought I would have an augmented matrix, solve for the solution set, and then if the solution set is a set of linear combinations I can write the vectors inside as a span?

Comment: @Lil see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finding the matrix representing $T$ is that straightforward. To find the
image of $T$, you should consider a set that $T$ maps to, or at least some
representation of this set. What might be a good idea is to find a basis for
this image and use this basis to define the vectors generatable within the
image.