# Find the image of the transformation and write as a span of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T(a,b)=(a+b,2a-b,3a)$

Find the image of $T$ (as a span of vectors).

So I created the augmented matrix and got this: 
$A$= $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & b_1\\2 & -1 & b_2\\ 3 &0 & b_3\end{bmatrix}$

then I did -3r1+r3 $A$= $\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1 &b_1\\2 & -1 & b_2\\ 0 &-3 & -3b_1+b_3\end{bmatrix}$

then I did -2r1+r2 $A$= $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & b_1\\0 & -3 & -2b_1+b_2\\ 0 &-3 & -3b_1+b_3 \end{bmatrix}$

Finally -b2+b3 $A$= $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & b_1\\0 & -3 & -2b_1+b_2\\ 0 &0 & -b_1-b_2+b_3\end{bmatrix}$

Now I know in order for the system to be consistent $-b_1-b_2+b_3$ must equal $0$ but how do I find the image of $T$ as a span of vectors?

Comment: Image of $T$ is spanned by (1,2,3) and (1,-1,0). What are you trying to do with the augmented matrix ?

Comment: I'm trying to find the restrictions regarding the b values

Comment: But doesn't that answer your question ? What is the need of finding these b values ?

Comment: at this point I have b3=b1+b2 but what is the actual span of vectors.. I'm just confused what my final answer would be. Do I solve each of those b's in terms of one variable?

Comment: You asked this yesterday and got a comprehensive answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647004/find-the-matrix-representing-t-and-find-the-image-of-t-as-a-span-of-vectors/1647051#1647051. There is no reason for you to row reduce the matrix (unless you suspect some of the vectors in your column space to be dependent on the others). The image is just $AX$ where $X \in F^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$T(a,b) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \end{pmatrix}a + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}b$, so image $T$ $=$ span$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ by definition.  No need to solve a system of linear equations for this question.

**EDIT**

If for some reason you *must* use row reduction: the condition for \begin{pmatrix} b1 \\ b2 \\ b3  \end{pmatrix} to be in image $T$ is $b3 = b1+b2$, as you calculated.  Thus $\begin{pmatrix} b1 \\ b2 \\ b3  \end{pmatrix} = b1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} + b2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$, so

\begin{equation} \mbox{image}\ T = \mbox{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} \right\}.
\end{equation}

You can see relatively easily that both answers are equivalent, by writing each vector as a linear combination of the vectors in the other set, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} + 2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: my professor told me I needed to find conditions with b for some reason.... not quite sure why though

Comment: @Lil OK then, see my edit.